# Copying source code and history from one GitLab project to another

Tags: gitlab

At GitLab I have project X1 with a lot of code.
Project X2 was created an empty project .

I want to copy all the source code, including commits history from project X1 to project X2.
Those project will develop independently in the future.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a Gitlab project to another Gitlab repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155915/how-to-copy-a-gitlab-project-to-another-gitlab-repository)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new project, you can [import an existing project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html). Or you can [copy the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155915/gitlab-copy-project-to-other-git-lab-repository):

```
git clone <old_url>
cd <repo_dir_name>
git remote add new_remote <new_url>
git push --all new_remote
```

Comment: The project is created by a tool that creates a bunch of things.

Comment: I am trying to understand the sequence of commands.  So basically I am adding project X2 as a new remote to project X1, then I am performing push to that new remote. What part of that takes the history of X1? Is it push --all?

Comment: @Victoriia Yes --all pushes all branches with history on new origin

Comment: Info: If you have created the new project with "Initialize with README", you will need to pull that in your master branch first, better don't initialize the new repo.