# Is it possible to duplicate a gitlab project?

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to give each student a replica of a preexisting project for a test. is it possible to duplicate a gitlab project (including its issues)?

Comment: btw, we have tried forking but:
1. this does not copy the issues
2. this is still connected to the main project

Comment: That comment should be included in your question. GitLab has an API, so this is certainly possible, see [this repo](https://github.com/gotsunami/gitlab-copy).

Comment: You clone the repository, push it to the target repository and recreate all issues.

Comment: In the question marked as duplicate, check [@GinoMemplin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55278088/86072)