# What is the best way to copy a repository into a new repository?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a repository A that I would like to copy into a new repository B. What is the best way to do this?

I know that I can use the command `git push --mirror https://github.com/<account>/B.git` from inside the directory of repository A. This is one way of doing it.

Is there a better or more straightforward way, involving cloning or forking? I'm unable to fork a repository from `<myaccount>/A` to `<myaccount>/B`.

Comment: You can either `git push --mirror` or `git clone --mirror`. That will create a repository that is (almost) identical. Not sure what exactly you like to happen with "copying a repository into a different repository).

Comment: If you don't want a fork, the simplest way is indeed through a mirror sandbox. Related to, though not duplicate of, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53155915/3216427

Comment: But my question is why aren't you able to create a fork? Forks have to have similar visibility to the original (e.g., forks of public repos are public). Is it some permission issue that's preventing the fork?

Comment: Also, please define "better". Better on what dimension?