# Github: how to sync old fork (including all tags) from original projects?

Tags: git, github, tags, synchronization

Github: how to sync old fork (including all tags) from original project?
I did pull all from upstream on Github website. but no new tags are included.

```
original project:   user1/project1
forked 5 years ago: user2/project1
                    made some changes
```

how to sync everything(master and tags) from the original project?

Tried to create a new fork from the same project. Not allowed. How to delete the old fork?

Comment: You can have two remotes for the same sandbox, update the sandbox from the original project and push all the branches and tags to the new project.

Comment: This question is different, but my answer there should help you sync everything from the original project. of if you chose to solve your issue that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156626/3216427

Comment: I find it odd, however, that you cannot get the tags directly from the original to the fork, that should normally work without difficulty right in GitHub. Do you get an error message or some other indication of what's going on? Have permissions or visibility changed on either of those repos?

Comment: no. There is a message box saying there are 9298 commits after my fork. After clicking the sync command, but no new tags were fetched.

Comment: I like to get the latest release(tag), then add my own changes.

Comment: The sync command only merges the code from master. How to get the latest tag into my fork? thanks.

Comment: Right, it indeed looks like the "fetch upstream" button is just for one branch at a time, not a particularly efficient solution. I recommend the solution in the answer I linked above: the `git push --tags new_remote` command will push all the tags, or you can use `git push new_remote tag_name` to push just the latest tag, if that's good enough.

Comment: Thanks. what is the new_remote? is it original or my fork? I am confused with push vs pull. Git show origin: point to my fork.

Comment: If you follow the procedure in the answer I pointed to, `origin` should refer to `user1/project`, the original repo, and `new_remote` should refer to your fork, `user2/project`. Pull/fetch/clone is always from a server to your local computer, while push is from your local computer to a server. What you want to do is original -> your computer -> fork, so you have to clone or fetch from the original to your computer, then push from your computer to your fork. Does that make more sense now?