# Difference Git Clone --mirror VS git clone --bare

Tags: git, github, gitlab

We are in process of migrating gerrit based repo to gitlab.Went through couple of documents.Which say to use git clone --bare,Then cd into repo.git,then run git push --mirror
Some doc say to git clone --mirror,Then cd into repo.git,then run git push --mirror

Couple of time i went through to understand difference between git clone --mirror VS git clone --bare.
Still i could understand it properly.If someone could explain it.
Which is appropriate option to use in order to migrate the repo to gitlab

I cannot use import option that GitHub provide as,Gerrit Server is in private network

Could someone please help out.Really stuck on difference between git clone --mirror VS git clone --bare

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for the `--mirror` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror)? It appears to directly address this question.

Comment: Here's an old answer of mine explaining how to do the migration you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156626/3216427 I don't explain the difference between mirror and bare there, but show a complete recipe using mirror.

Comment: Git's `git clone` normally copies all (or most) *commits* and *no branch names*. Instead, you get all-new branch names. A `--bare` clone has no working tree so that you cannot do any work in it, and a `--mirror` clone adds "copy all refs, including all branch and non-branch names" atop the `--bare`. That's all there is to it, but since a repository proper is *two* databases and `--mirror` copies the *second* one as well as the first one, that's what you need here. However...

Comment: ... a GitHub or GitLab repository comes with a *third* database of issues and other add-ons, and `--mirror` cannot copy this third database as it lies outside the repository. So if you wish to copy more than just the two repository databases, you need some non-Git software as well. (Note that Gerrit may add yet more items beyond this. I haven't actually *used* Gerrit but it clearly has additional data; whether you'll need that copied too, I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

A clone copies the refs from the remote and stuffs them into a subdirectory named 'these are the refs that the remote has'.

A mirror copies the refs from the remote and puts them into its own top level - it replaces its own refs with those of the remote.

This means that when someone pulls from your mirror and stuffs the mirror's refs into thier subdirectory, they will get the same refs as were on the original. The result of fetching from an up-to-date mirror is the same as fetching directly from the initial repo

Comment: That's not *quite* right: a regular clone copies tags, for instance, without putting them under `refs/remotes/`. It replaces *branch* names with remote-tracking names (what you're referring to in your first paragraph), and it completely drops other names such as `refs/replace/` namespace names. But it's true that the OP needs `--mirror` here: that's *necessary*, it just might not be *sufficient*.