# Pushing code from a repository with no permissions to private repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a folder from an external repository (let's call it ExRepo) where I don't have any push permission. I have a personal repo called MyOwnRepo.

How do I get the ExRepo and merge it into MyOwnRepo?

I have tried this:

```
C:/Users/<User>/MyOwnRepo>git checkout -b ExRepo
C:/Users/<User>/MyOwnRepo>git clone git@ExRepo.git
C:/Users/<User>/MyOwnRepo>git remote add -f ExRepo git@MyOwnRepo.git
C:/Users/<User>/MyOwnRepo>git push
```

This doesn't really change anything at all. Most likely since the ExRepo is it's own repository inside another repository (MyOwnRepo). So how the hell do I get everything from ExRepo onto MyOwnRepo? If I try to add the folder ExRepo to my remote with URL to MyOwnRepo I get this message:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> lab3
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached lab3
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

BUT. If I treat ExRepo as a submodule I still can't edit it at all. Pushing the submodule won't give me a ExRepo folder to MyOwnRepo, just a link the original ExRepo where I don't have any permissions. So there's something I'm missing here obviously.

Comment: Yeah… if you don’t have push permissions you can’t push. Doesn’t matter if it’s a submodule in a different repo or not. You’ll have to fork the repo, or just clone it and then change the remote to push to a repository you actually have push rights to

Comment: What you need is one sandbox (not nested sandboxes, just one sandbox) with two remotes. You can fetch from either, but only push to the one where you have write access. That should solve your problem. This old answer of mine to a different question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156626/3216427

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have a single sandbox that is connected to both repos, not nested sandboxes. You will be able to fetch from either repo, but you will only be able to push to the one where you have write access.

Let's assume the read-only repo is `git@server:exspace/exrepo.git` and your read-write repo is `git@server:newspace/myownrepo.git`. This procedure should work for you. Don't run this in an existing sandbox, or else skip the clone part if you already have a clone of exrepo.

```
git clone git@server:exspace/exrepo.git myrepo
cd myrepo
git remote add myownremote git@server:newspace/myownrepo.git
```

Now, to push some branch `branchname` from exrepo to myownremote , you can check it out and push it:

```
git checkout branchname
git push myownremote branchname
```

and if you want to make your life easy afterwards and have your own repo as the default, set it as the upstream:

```
git push -u myownremote branchname
```

On every future push/pull/fetch operation, you can specify which remote you want to use, `origin` or `myownremote`.