# Built a project from source, how to link it to a forked repository on Github?

Tags: git, github, open-source

I want to start contributing to an open source project I've been using for a few years. I'm new to Github. I built the project from source on my computer, but I have noticed that I do not actually have the project I've built from source linked to my Github account. I have forked the repository so that I can now make changes on it. How can I now set it up so that the changes I make on my computer (where I built the project from source) are reflected in my forked repository?

Comment: "*I built the project from source on my computer…*" Please clarify how did you do that? Have you cloned the repository or just downloaded source code?

Comment: Just add a second remote to your sandbox, pointing to your fork. E.g., see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649763/3216427

Comment: But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/are-git-forks-actually-git-clones/6286877#6286877 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-on-github/9257901#9257901 for more general information on forks.

Comment: And the GitHub manual on forks is well written, it is work taking the time to read it: https://docs.github.com/fr/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo